Efficiently Matching Complex JSONB Criteria and Notifying Users in PostgreSQL
I am developing a PostgreSQL-based (with Supabase) system where new entries in a cars table must be matched against user-defined preferences stored in a monitoring_preferences table, each containing criteria in JSONB format. Additionally, users can select attributes to monitor via a "facets" table, which specifies JSONB paths against which new car data should be queried.
cars table structure:

id INT
car_data JSONB

Example cars entry:
{
  "model": "m3",
  "price": 45000,
  "features": {
    "color": ["BLUE"],
    "interior": "leather",
    "wheels": "18in"
  }
}

monitoring_preferences table structure:

id INT

criteria JSONB array


Example monitoring_preferences entry:
[{"selector": "car_data->'features'->>'color'", "operator": "=", "value": "[\"BLUE\"]"}]

facets table structure:

id UUID

path TEXT

description TEXT

type TEXT

values JSONB

order INT

operator TEXT


Example facets entry:
{
  "path": "car_data->INTERIOR",
  "description": "Interior Color",
  "type": "select",
  "values": [{"value":["PREMIUM_BLACK","BLACK_TEXTILE","BLACK"],"description":"Black"}, {"value":["PREMIUM_WHITE","WHITE"],"description":"White"}, {"value":["CREAM"],"description":"Cream"}],
  "order": 7,
  "operator": "in"
}


Monitoring Specific Attributes: For instance, to monitor all cars with a black interior, users would add the following to their criteria array:
{
  "path": "car_data->INTERIOR",
  "values": [{"value": ["PREMIUM_BLACK", "BLACK_TEXTILE", "BLACK"], "operator": "in"}]
}


The reason for using an array of values is to accommodate the variations in naming across different car models.
Main Goal: The primary goal is to efficiently query this nested and complex JSONB data to find matching cars and send notifications to users when a new car that fits their criteria becomes available.
Challenges:

Efficiently indexing and querying large, nested JSONB data in PostgreSQL.

Dynamically generating SQL queries based on user-defined JSONB paths and values.

Implementing a notification system that alerts users about new matching cars.


Questions:

How can I efficiently index and query large, nested JSONB data in PostgreSQL to improve performance?

What strategies or tools are recommended for dynamically generating and executing these SQL queries based on user-defined JSONB paths and values?

Are there best practices for implementing a notification system within this architecture to alert users when a match is found?


I am looking for advice or examples from those who have tackled similar challenges in dynamic data matching systems, especially those requiring timely user notifications. Any insights or guidance would be greatly appreciated.
Today I'm using Firebase to notify users, but it's very static and not very easy to maintain.

Welcome to stackoverflow. You should make more direct and specific questions here.
But what you can do is to create a computed column based on that values field within the JSONB.

JSON works great in PostgreSQL, but it's by far not the most efficient. Performance can be good enough however. Check the GIN indexes: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/datatype-json.html#JSON-INDEXING
